# Update state according to screen size on load and on screen resize

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom

The function is supposed to change the navigation bar when there is a resize and on load. The problem is it doesn't work immediately.

On chrome devtools, it triggers after 1 second; on a few mobiles, I've tested it, and it works after scrolling down to the bottom or rotating the screen and coming back.

```
const [mobile, setMobile] = useState(false);

const handleResize = () => {
        if (window.innerWidth <= 468) {
            setMobile(true);
        } else {
            setMobile(false);
        }
    };

    window.addEventListener('load', handleResize);
    window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize);

 return (
        <nav
            className={
                navColor
                    ? css.nav__container
                    : `${css.nav__container} ${css.nav__blur}`
            }>
            <a
                href='#'
                onClick={() => setActiveNav('#')}
                className={activeNav === '#' ? css.nav__active : ''}>
                {mobile ? <RiHome3Line /> : 'Home'}
           </a>
       </nav>
```

I tried to change const to function(); I expect it to work on load, not after some time.

Comment: check to see where this script is located in the html? if it is loaded in the header, it might not trigger after the page loads. it would try to trigger before page loads and thus do nothing

Comment: Hi Majeev! I posted an answer; check it and let me know please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use only `resize` with an `useEffect` to have something more React-like. Here is an example:

```js
const [mobile, setMobile] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
  const handleResize = () => {
    if (window.innerWidth <= 468) {
      setMobile(true);
    } else {
      setMobile(false);
    }
  };
  // runs on load
  handleResize();
  // runs when the screen size changes
  window.addEventListener("resize", handleResize);
  // remove the event listener before the component gets unmounted
  return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", handleResize);
}, []);
```

Comment: Works fine now. Could you also tell me why we need to remove event listener in this situation?

Comment: Glad it did work. About your last question, do you know a component can get mounted and unmounted multiple times? I guess so. Well, without this cleanup function, you will end up having multiple event listeners in memory, one per mount, which is bad.